Movie with a magic trick gone wrong
I have thought about this scene for pretty regularly growing up and to this day I don't know what it is from.
What I remember is there is a man laying on a circular table in front of an audience. His arms and legs are restrained to the table and there are swords hanging from the ceiling. Periodically one of them falls and he has to get out of his restraints before they do.
From what I remember he gets out of one I think but then is impaled in the arm and I think later in the chest. 
I want to say the audience did not know this was going to happen but there was foul play.
I was born 1990 and I probably saw it between 8-14. So that makes it between 1998 and 2004.
I think that there were boards that contained his appendages. He was laying like a star and on the side of his head, legs, and arms were boards to keep them still. That way when a sword fell he couldn't move his arm or leg out of the way if he was still restrained.

Ok - any more detail would be helpful - for example where did you see this and when.  We don't know when you were 'growing up' and it help exclude more recent movies.

haha good point.

Please try to add anything that may help identification. Was it in Color or Black & White? What time period was it showing? What country was it likely from or what language was it in? Are there any other plot details you remember? Descriptions of scenes or names of characters or actors you can give? Anything at all? Feel free to [edit] any additional details into the question. For help writing a good identification question, see: Identify-This-X Questions.
